# How to save the current display of Ggobi with rggobi?

Tags: r, rggobi

When creating several graphics with Ggobi, there's always one and only one current display (selected by the user by clicking on this graphic). With the `ggobi_display_save_picture()` function of the `rggobi` package, one has to specify the numbering of the plot we want to save. But is there a way to save the current display, without knowing its numbering ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the ggobi display with the largest number:

```
ggobi_display_save_picture(display=displays(ggobi_get(ggobi_count())[[1]])
```

Substitute an integer value for `ggobi_count()` if you want a different one. See:

```
?rggobi::ggobi_display_save_picture
?rggobi::ggobi_get
```

Comment: The current display is not necessarily the last one, it is selected by the user. I have read the help a dozen a times, there's nothing about what I'm looking for. Michael Lawrence has given a solution here https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ggobi/dNSPKDcT5Dg/discussion